# Disable alert: "Cellular data disabled for [app]"

Tags: ios, cellular-data

The above alert pops up every time I open an app whose access to cellular data I've turned off. This adds an unnecessary step every time I launch one of these apps. My feeling is, "Who cares if cellular data is disabled for Photos? I just want to see my damn photos." This happens with 3rd party and native apps alike. I first noticed the issue in iOS 7 and am seeing it again in iOS 8. Is there a way to turn off these alerts?

Comment: There is no way to disable it, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way to stop seeing that alert every time you open the app from the cellular data network.

Every time the app tries to connect to the Internet, then you'll see that alert.

In fact, there is one way you'll probably won't like, but just in case... If you put your phone on airplane mode, then you won't see that message (though you'll see the annoying "no data connection" if you perform any activity that asks for connection anyway).