# Notes and cellular data notifications

Tags: ios

How do you stop the notifications on the notes that says the cellular data is off? I know it is off. I turned it off. I do not want my notes on my phone and my iPad to sync. Both places gets messed up.

Comment: Why not just turn off Notes syncing instead of turning off cellular data all together? There is no way to disable the Cellular Data notification in any app. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158441/disable-alert-cellular-data-disabled-for-app